# Using @react-oauth/google and confused on wrapping app with GoogleOAuthProvider

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, react-context

I am using @react-oauth/google to handle google Oauth login and want to use react Context to store the `AuthContext`(see if the user is log in)

I am confused on which of the following I should do on my App.tsx:

Option 1:

```
<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId='xxxx'>
     <AuthContext.Provider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
              <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
              <Route path="blogs" element={<BlogsPage />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
</GoogleOAuthProvider>
```

Option 2:

```
  <AuthContext.Provider>
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId='xxxx'>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
                  <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
                  <Route path="blogs" element={<BlogsPage />} />
                </Route>
              </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
```

Which one here is the best practive? Or neither?